# Are extra semicolons allowed inside struct declarations?

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer

This question is by mere curiosity. It is *not* about the empty struct.

I just stumbled over an interesting typo of the kind

```
struct {
     int member1; /*comment*/ ; /* <-- note the ';' */
     int member2;
} variable[] = { /* initializers */ };
```

which the compiler (xc32, derived from gcc) accepted without any
complaints. Of course, I corrected this but the software was running 
smoothly before and after the correction and the additional `;` seemingly 
causes no problems. I then tried various lengthes of `;;;` in he struct definition an they seem to make no difference neither to functionality 
nor to `sizeof`. So in a `struct` any sequence of `;;;;` seems to be 
equivalent to a single `;`.

I couldn't find anything about such "empty members" of a struct/union
in the specification, neither that they are allowed nor that they are 
disallowed. To me it seems as if the grammar rejected them. This contrasts 
to "empty declarations" `;` at the top level of a compilation unit, which the 
standard clearly forbids and the "null" statement `;` in functions which is a 
clearly allowed language feature.

Does anyone know about this behaviour? Is it compiler specific or does the 
C specification somehow tolerate such empty struct members?

Comment: However, ordinary statements (like `x=y+2;` or `puts("aa");` or blocks) cannot appear inside a `struct` definition. Why can empty *statements* appear in it, but not other kind of statements?

Comment: @P.P. Not a duplicate. This semicolon is inside `struct` declaration. **Not** a null-statement.

Comment: @P.P.  This isn't really a duplicate. `;` is not a statement inside the declaration. My answer is moot whatever the upvotes, I have deleted it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have already reopened it.

Comment: @P.P. I had my finger on the button :) thanks.

Comment: My guess is that compilers tolerate it, since they are harmless. They expect one or more `;`.

Comment: 2 downvotes and no answers? come on!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not the downvoter, but I think the answer to this question will be a boring parsing check, not very interesting. This [pedantic link](https://godbolt.org/g/JK1dyk) already answers the question.

Comment: @liliscent you should make that an answer. As now we're suspecting that it's implementation defined.

Comment: Your actual code have 3 pedantics errors... http://rextester.com/XKKK47051

Comment: Well, my actual initializer list (not the example here) is non-empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard doesn't talk about that, it's just a `gcc` tolerance. See [6.7.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1):

> ```
> struct-or-union-specifier:
>               struct-or-union identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }
>               struct-or-union identifier
> struct-or-union:
>              struct
>              union
> struct-declaration-list:
>              struct-declaration
>              struct-declaration-list struct-declaration
> struct-declaration:
>              specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-listopt ;
>              static_assert-declaration
> specifier-qualifier-list:
>             type-specifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
>             type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
> ```

(`type-specifier` and `type-qualifier` can't be empty, see the related sections in the standard for details.)

---

Some compilers, like gcc, tolerate extra semi-colons, but `-Wpedantic` option reveals that it's only a tolerance:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    ;;;
};

int main() {
    ;;;
}
```

With -pedantic option gcc complains, not on the main empty statements, but on the extra semicolons of the structure declaration.

```
<source>:3:5: warning: extra semicolon in struct or union specified [-Wpedantic]
     ;;;
     ^
<source>:3:6: warning: extra semicolon in struct or union specified [-Wpedantic]
     ;;;
      ^
<source>:3:7: warning: extra semicolon in struct or union specified [-Wpedantic]
     ;;;
```

Other compilers may not be that friendly, so the typo must be fixed, since it doesn't bring anything useful.

Comment: What kind of statements can appear inside a `struct` declaration? (intuitively, I would believe that none)

Comment: This is wrong. You're referring to the compound-statement section, which is irrelevant to the question. Instead, it's part of [**declaration**](https://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#6.7.2.1). And an extra semicolon is [pedantically wrong](https://godbolt.org/g/c6vE8B).

Comment: there's nothing specific in the norm about declarations and semicolons, you're right.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Sidenote: ISO9899 is a _standard_, not just a _norm_. Maybe they are perfect false friends in your language (I know they are in English/German)

Comment: first time I'm quoting the norm (standard, sorry) in an answer :) Edited

Comment: Well, actually you didn't quote it. I corrected that, if you don't mind ;-) (bookmarking the document I linked might be helpful)

Comment: I don't mind at all. thanks. BTW as you see there are still some interesting C questions.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax is specified in C11 6.7.2.1

> *struct-declaration:
>
>     specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-listopt **;**
>
>     static_assert-declaration*

There is 1 semicolon at the end, so that's the only allowed syntax. You cannot skip the semicolon, you can't add extra ones. And that's that.

(You can however have a static assert inside a struct declaration, from C11.)

Comment: however some compilers tolerate that (and issue a warning)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I noticed gcc does, which is why compiling with `-pedantic-errors` is a good idea if strict C standard conformance is important. Adding extra semi-colons would make the code non-standard and non-portable.

Comment: I have added the gcc missing bit. I hope you don't mind (I cannot undelete my wrongly upvoted answer for this, but I think lilliscent comment deserves to be officialized)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I do mind it, since I don't really care about what gcc does and does not in "gnu poop mode". If gcc is to be used, always compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` or otherwise that compiler is kind of dangerous. No other C compiler accepts this, I just tried two different ones (IAR and Codewarrior) and they give compiler errors by default.

Comment: no worries, I just made my answer CW (with all the wrong upvotes and all :)) and added my bit. Feel free to downvote :) (sorry about OP accepting my answer instead... that wasn't meant for this, since it's CW)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's not incorrect, just irrelevant. In "gnu poop mode" you can write all manner of crazy non-C, such as zero-sized arrays.